# Do any text tagging NLP tools use a relational database or anything other than text files to annotate texts?

Tags: text, databases, annotation

I am learning about how production systems implement text tagging. MILA has [this XML format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77463712/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-xml-nodes-and-attributes-in-the-mila-data-format-for), and according to ChatGPT, [Brat](https://brat.nlplab.org/examples.html) has a text file format, though haven't found much examples of that other than [this](https://brat.nlplab.org/standoff.html). ChatGPT said Brat had an option to persist the annotations to a relational database, but didn't know what the structure of the schema was. TEI uses and XML file as well.

First part of the question is why is everyone using files to manage the text annotations, not a relational database? I get that it's easier to get started using XML files, but it seems a nightmare to collaborate on annotating a text if everyone is working on the same file (is it even possible?). You would have to use version control / git or something it seems to manage the collaboration, and that means you need to be staring at the XML file a lot, plus using any UI they have.

Second part of the question, what are some key examples of text tagging systems that use a relational database? And do you know if they have any docs demonstrating their relational schema? I am really curious ultimately how this is implemented in a relational database. I can imagine how to make a set of tables by looking at XML files (like the MILA example), but I'd like to see how they actually do it.

Relational databases could solve the collaboration problem by doing real-time syncing with web-sockets on the annotations or something like that. However, I see a problem where, like the MILA example doing `text/paragraph/sentence/token`, at first you would just have `text` and no `paragraphs`. Someone might annotate a `token` next, before any paragraphs exist, then what is supposed to happen to the data model, link the token to the `text`? So there is some problems I have to think about how you would model this in a RDBMS, which is why I'm looking for inspiration.

If no systems exist, why not? Why not use a relational database, what are the problems as applied to text annotation systems?

Comment: Usually, when a tool is created for a specific purpose, the less assumptions it makes outside that purpose, the more adaptable it will be. Taggers just tag text; if they would store their result in a relational database, which one should it use and why not another one? It's easy to insert the output of a text tagger to a database from the text file. You can just do that. Also, an advice: don't trust ChatGPT for factual knowledge; it makes up stuff all the time.